# Changing the position of next and prev buttons in datepicker plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've changed the image of next button with:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon {
    background: url(next.png);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

As you see the new image size is 50x50, and the old one was 16x16.
Now I don't know how to position the new image correctly, since right now it looks like [this - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx65L1b9/).

Comment: could you please create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify or override in you own css file: `.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span` and `.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span`.

something like this should do the job:

```
left: 0;
margin-left: 0;
top: 0;
margin-top: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

change the css to this

For reference check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amx261cv/)

```
.ui-datepicker-next span {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/DyQTbOA.png); !important;

}
.ui-datepicker-prev span {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/DyQTbOA.png); !important;

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

- change the top and left position of the next and prev icons
- adjust the title height

The snippet:

```js
$(function(){
    
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#thealtdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon{
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DyQTbOA.png);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 6px;
  left: -10px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/hBFw2TW.png);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
}
.ui-datepicker div.ui-datepicker-title {
  line-height: 2.4em; !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should just resize the your new image.

Another solution is; using position, set the position absolute to your image as you see in code snippet. (without resizing the image)

```js
$(function(){
    
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#thealtdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker {
  font-size: 25px !important;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/DyQTbOA.png);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left:0px;
    top:9px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/hBFw2TW.png);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:12px;
    top:9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```